# AutoMapper using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, automapper

I want to use Automapper with linq select statement. I am not able to find
how can I implement this.

Please help me for sort out this,

```
return studentData.Select(studData => new student {
  Enable = true,
  Name = studData.Name,
  Result = studData.Result,
  Class = studData.Class,
  Address = studData.Address,  
  Country= getCountry(Country),             
  State = studData.State,
  City = studData.City,
  Mobile = studData.Mobile
}).ToList();
```

This is not mapped directly because I have customized fields that are

Enable , Country.

I am not directly mapping like this

```
return studentData.Select(studData => mapper.map<Student>(studData))}).ToList();
```

If I were to use simple without linq then I will customized that field like

```
var student = studentData.Select(studData => mapper.map<Student>(studData))}).ToList();
student.Enable = true;
student.Country= getCountry(Country);
return student;
```

Then how can I customized field in Auto Mapper using Linq?

Comment: Your statement doesn't work anyway because you can't use `getCountry` in an LINQ-to-entities query. You have to fix that first. AutoMapper won't do that for you.

Comment: yes i know automapper not do any thing for getCountry, I have to write as costume for it but I am not able to find that how can I write custome in  Linq select

Comment: have you tried to put the mapping to custom fields in the automapper definiton ? for example:  Mapper.CreateMap< Student, StudentDTO>()
                  .ForMember(x => x.Country, y => y.MapFrom(z => getCountry(z.Country)))

Comment: Yes , I tried but it is not possible because of my project architecture I am not able to find getCountry() method where I used CreateMap

Comment: Try this : studentData.Cast<Student>().Select(x => ..........

Comment: So if I get you well, you're trying to jump through hoops to make AutoMapper use a function you won't be able to use in a LINQ-to-Entities query. My advice: don't use AutoMapper if it makes things more complicated than without it + refactor `getCountry` to code that can be used inside the LINQ query. If you need help with *that*, fine, but that should be another question.